# Request en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, jwt

Estoy llamando a una ruta de laravel a la cual le añado en el Header el 'email' y 'password', pero desde el controlador no consigo recoger esa información.

Haciendo pruebas observo que cuando pinto el objeto request completo:

```
return $request;
```

Sí que muestra la información que necesito pero cuando ejecuto por ejemplo:

```
return $request->all() ;
```

me devuelve un array vacio `[]`

La petición la estoy haciendo desde postman:

[image: header in postman]

Y el código del controlador únicamente es:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
  $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);

  return $request->all();
}
```

Si el return es :

```
return $request;
```

La respuesta en postman es:

> POST /public/auth_login HTTP/1.1 Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: gzip,
>   deflate, br Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8 Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 0 Cookie:
>   laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImJQaWhTa3hkdjdnY1dnTXU5VkdJV1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiakcxaHBpM1JlUk0yWXZwMEt4a1B1dk5oVzdMa2wxanp3SDFwV0w5WUx1T3pPaXRcL2pmczkwMUd2elFtcXVMSEVPd3NhOVwvUVI1S3Fmdyt0KzZ1SlRmdz09IiwibWFjIjoiMTY2MzRiYmZkYzg4ODhmODE5N2FkMWYyZGE3YTc4N2NiOTU0MTNlYzY4NTdlZDEzMjBmYzEyNzFkYTE3ODMwZiJ9
>   **Email: linux@linux.es** Host: localhost:8080 Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop **Password:
>   12345** Postman-Token: 1102e9a3-a6d6-80bf-dc6c-45bf8e053ef0
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36

¿Qué puede pasar?

Comment: Hola, agrega el código de la vista y el controlador por favor.

Comment: Hola Shaz ya he actualizado la pregunta con el código, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claramente en postman estan mal ingresados los parametros, en la pestaña Headers debes poner el `Content-type`

Y tus parametros van en el body :

[image: postman body]

Comment: Hola sioesi, de esta manera que has puesto funciona, pero no consigo rescatar con laravel los datos de manera iindividual, la respuesta de postman es esta:

Comment: POST /public/auth_login HTTP/1.1
Accept:          */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8
Cache-Control:   no-cache
Connection:      keep-alive
Content-Length:  50
Content-Type:    application/json
Cookie:          laravel_session=eyJp...
Host:            localhost:8080
Origin:          chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinj...
Postman-Token:   e2d4f8a1-827d-b431-7826-b8e477198db9
User-Agent:      Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36

{
 "email":'linux@linux.es',
 "password":'12345'
}

Comment: Hazle un return a tu data, y que imprime la respuesta

Comment: Pero el problema es que no consigo con laravel obtener esos datos de manera individual, he probado con estas lineas

Comment: Bastaria con $response->tuDato

Comment: $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']); --no devuelve nada
$email = $request->input('email'); ---sacado de la web de laravel de la sección 'Retrieving JSON Input Values' pero no devuelve nada
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true); tampoco consigo obtener los datos...

Comment: return $request->email; esta linea devuelve vacio

Comment: Antes de crear la variable credencial, retorna los mismos parametros que llegan , retorna $request

Comment: Request me retorna:

Comment: POST /public/auth_login HTTP/1.1
Accept:          */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8
Cache-Control:   no-cache
Connection:      keep-alive
Content-Length:  50
Content-Type:    application/json
Cookie:          laravel_session=eyJ...
Host:            localhost:8080
Origin:          chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflin..
Postman-Token:   0ae24d32-5666-9ac0-61ae-0b4377303d8e
User-Agent:      Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36

{
 "email":'linux@linux.es',
 "password":'12345'
}

Comment: Probaste dd($request->all()); ???

Comment: dd($request->all()) me devuelve un array vacío

Comment: Si devuelvo esto return $request->json(); me devuelve el error The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.

Comment: Y return Input::get('email') ?

Comment: Ya lo saqué!! madre mia, era porque en el json el dato debe ir entre comillas dobles y yo las tenia simples!!! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!!

Comment: todo el dia en esto....

Comment: XD!!! Pense que habias visto la imagen que te deje en mi respuesta!! Un saludo! Exito

Comment: si, pero a las comillas no le di importancia y vi un comentario en la pag de php http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php que dice 
// las comillas simples no son válidas

Comment: gracias!!!!!!!!!!!!